# open popup at click position responsive issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have done a popup click is triggered on window. Popup must be shown at wherever the event is triggered.But there are some problem

Popup must be shown at current visible window.Meaning,If I clicked at right and bottom most part of the window so hidden in small window at right side window

so how to change position depend up on the screen size or else some other options?
[image]

```
var xpos = 0; // mouse x position
var ypos = 0; // mouse y position
var mouseYPos = 0; // mouse y position from top of the screen where we clicked
var mouseXPos = 0; // mouse x position from left of the screen where we clicked
var screenHeight = screen.height; //Actual height of the screen
    var screenWidth  = screen.width; //Actual width of the screen
    //mouseYPos - mouse clicked position from top of the screen 
    if (mouseYPos < 110)
    {
        ypos = ypos + 50;
    } else if ((mouseYPos > 111)&&(mouseYPos < 500))
    {
        ypos = ypos - 0;
    } 
    else if (mouseYPos > 501)
    {
        ypos = ypos -210;
    } 
//mouseXPos - mouse clicked position from left of the screen 

    if ((mouseXPos+ 50) > screenWidth)
    {
        xpos = xpos - 220;
    }
    if (!winCal)
    {
        headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];

        // add javascript function to the span cal
        e = document.createElement("script");
        e.type = "text/javascript";
        e.language = "javascript";
        e.text = funcCalback;
        headID.appendChild(e);
        // add stylesheet to the span cal

        cssStr = ".calTD {text-align: center; border:0; }\n";
        cssStr += ".calR {text-align: center; font-weight: bold;}";

        style = document.createElement("style");
        style.type = "text/css";
        style.rel = "stylesheet";
        if (style.styleSheet)
        { // IE
            style.styleSheet.cssText = cssStr;
        }
        else
        { // w3c
            cssText = document.createTextNode(cssStr);
            style.appendChild(cssText);
        }

        headID.appendChild(style);
        // create the outer frame that allows the cal. to be moved
        span = document.createElement("span");
        span.id = calSpanID;
        span.style.position = "absolute";
        span.style.left = (xpos + CalPosOffsetX) + 'px';
        span.style.top = (ypos - CalPosOffsetY) + 'px';
        span.style.width = CalWidth + 'px';
        //span.style.border = "solid 1pt " + SpanBorderColor;
        span.style.padding = "0";
        //span.style.cursor = "move";
        //span.style.backgroundColor = SpanBgColor;
        span.style.zIndex = 100;
        document.body.appendChild(span);
        winCal = document.getElementById(calSpanID);
    }
    else
    {
        winCal.style.visibility = "visible";
        winCal.style.Height = calHeight;

        // set the position for a new calendar only
        if (bNewCal === true)
        {
            winCal.style.left = (xpos + CalPosOffsetX) + 'px';
            winCal.style.top = (ypos - CalPosOffsetY) + 'px';
        }
    }

    winCal.innerHTML = winCalData + vCalHeader + vCalData + vCalTime + vCalClosing;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you create and share a fiddle and mention the exact issue. This will be helpful for understanding your question.

Comment: its date picker when i click right side calculator img, popup half hidden in small screen

Comment: its the big code so sorry for fiddle add image